# Asynchronously Loaded SVG-Filter feColorMatrix Working in Chrome, not in Safari or Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am loading a SVG-filter asynchronously depending on the user's date and time. It works fine on Chrome, but not in Safari/Firefox.

### Reduced example

**1. HTML:**
By clicking on the button, we will load a svg-string into the DIV#svg-loader:

```
<img src="http://beta.zonabern.ch/project/uploads/img0136-640x480.jpg" alt="" />

<div id="svg-loader"></div>
<button id="loader">Load</button>
```

**2. CSS:** The filter-property is supported with the vendor-prefix

```
img {
  filter: url("#monochrome");
  -webkit-filter: url("#monochrome");
}
```

**3. Javascript/JQuery**: By clicking on the button, I simulate an asynchronous loading of the svg-data.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#loader' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $( '#svg-loader' ).empty().html('<svg class="defs-only"><filter id="monochrome" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" values="0.33984375 0 0 0 0.66015625 0.4140625 0 0 0 0.5859375 0.3203125 0 0 0 0.6796875 0 0 0 1 0"/></filter></svg>');
    });
});
```

For better readability, again the svg:

```
<svg class="defs-only">
    <filter id="monochrome" 
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" 
            x="0" 
            y="0" 
            height="100%" 
            width="100%">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"
                       values="0.33984375 0 0 0 0.66015625
                               0.4140625  0 0 0 0.5859375
                               0.3203125  0 0 0 0.6796875
                               0          0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

This filter should turn the image above into a violet-white image.

See the Codepen-Example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWmqXx), working in Chrome, but not in Safari/Firefox.

Comment: works for me on FF47 on mac os and Safari 9.1

Comment: If you put the CSS in a separate file you must prefix the # with the name of the html file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to assign your `filter` CSS rules to a class:

```
.filtered {
  filter: url("#monochrome");
  -webkit-filter: url("#monochrome");
}
```

Then only assign that class to the `<img>` once the SVG has loaded.

```
$( '#loader' ).on( 'click', function() {
  $( '#svg-loader' ).empty().html('<svg>...</svg>');
  $("#myimg").addClass("filtered");
});
```

[Updated codepen here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNEoqN)  This works on FF. I can't test Safari because I am on a PC.